# Bathroom exhaust fan/light swtch

Tags: electrical, bathroom

Bathroom fan burned out. Got a new one, installed it, motor hums, fan won't spin. Replaced the switch, now motor won't even hum. What kind of switch do I need?

Comment: Are you using an ordinary switch for this, or some sort of smart-switch, dimmer, or the likes?

Comment: A picture or two of the switch that shows which wires connect to which terminals would be helpful.